# OpenGL.: Zoom irregular part of main buffer

Tags: opengl

How can I zoom irregular part of main buffer? I would also need to apply border texture to that part.

To make it simple, I'm simulating magnification glass.

Update:
Let's try with simplest example:
 1. 2D rendering, draw image (texture) full screen.
 2. Get any non square (round and polygon are fine) area of that.
 3. Increase it's dimensions twice.
 4. Apply another texture which will cover border area of taken image. It will be transparent in the middle.
 5. Draw that back to a main buffer.

I can provide screenshot of my idea if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using stencil and FBO.

1. Copy area which need to be zoomed from main buffer to temporary FBO.
2. Apply if you need any drawings on it.
3. Switch back to drawing on main buffer.
4. Create stencil mask to protect drawing on parts you don't want.
5. Draw texture created by temporary FBO.
6. Clear stencil buffer

Comment: Why haven't you?
I can delete this answer of course if you like but it might be useful for someone else. I have found out this after hours of experimenting after not receiving correct answer.

If you say it is not an answer I'll remove it :D

Comment: Updated answer. Does it seems more like answer?

Comment: I would be happy to mark your answer as correct if you make it.
Thanks

Comment: I do not have an answer, I was just commenting that your original attempt at answering was not really an answer. This is much better.

Answer (score 1):

There are [ready to use](https://gist.github.com/detunized/1317940) pixel shaders that will mignify part of your scene in place or if you need to render the mignification at a custom position, you could render with a `FBO` with two texture attached, one for the complete scene, and one for the zoom portion.

Comment: I see this asnwer as potentially usefull. But I still don't see how that will work in my case. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Give maybe more information on your current context, I could be more precise.

Comment: @Predrag Manojlovic: You need to master `FBO` to render to texture, that's maybe what's confuse you. search google for 'render to texture with fbo', that's a first step. The mignification shader is not very complicated. I've used one in a puzzle game but that's directX shader, but I could past it if you wants.

Comment: I already do that with FBO but with square area and zoom it by blitting back to main buffer. I need to do with round or polygonal area.

Comment: here is my directX shader, it's rouded zoom. I miss time to convert to glsl, maybe later: float2 centerToPixel = uv - Center * dd;
 float dist = length(centerToPixel/ float2(1, dd.y/dd.x) );
 float ratio = smoothstep(InnerRadius, max(InnerRadius, OuterRadius), dist);
 float2 samplePoint = lerp(Center*dd + centerToPixel / Magnification, uv, ratio);
 
 return tex2D(Texture1Sampler, samplePoint);

Comment: Solved by using stencil.